# What is the difference between these two fields / methods?

Tags: c++, class, field

I've started working with classes in C++ and I found two different declarations of fields:

```
type ClassName::*var;
```

and

```
type *ClassName::var;
```

What is the difference between them?

EDIT: One more question can methods be declared like this:

```
type *ClassName::method_one(...);
type ClassName::*method_two(...);
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Can you post an example of the declaration of `ClassName`?

Comment: No, I don't have any, unfortunately. :(

Comment: One is a pointer to a member, the other is a member that's a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different. The first one declares a ***pointer to member variable of type `type`***.

The second one is a ***static definition of member `var` of class `ClassName` which is of type `type*`.***

Third one (even though incomplete) is a definition of a ***member function that returns `type*`***

Fourth one is a declaration of a ***pointer to a member function which returns `type`***.

---

```
class A {
public :
   int i;
   static int *j;
   int* f();
   int g() { std::cout << "g" << std::endl; }
};

int* A::j;                // First one
int* A::f() { }           // Third one

int main() {
    A a;

    int A::*i_ptr;        // Second one
    i_ptr = &A::i;    
    a.*i_ptr = 2;         // Modifying a.i

    int (A::*mem_fn) ();  // Fourth one
    mem_fn = &A::g;
    (a.*mem_fn)();        // calling a.g()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One is a *pointer-to-member*, the other is a *member that is a pointer*.

If you're using the declaration for something like static initialization:

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    static int *member, *othermember;
};

int SomeClass::*member = 0;
int *SomeClass::othermember = 0;
```

Although this compiles fine, if you actually *use* `member` you'll get a linker error (as opposed to `othermember`, because you're defining a pointer-to-member; not a member-that-is-a-pointer.

With your function definitions:

```
class SomeOtherClass {
public:
    static int *function();
};

int *SomeOtherClass::function() { return 0; } // This will work
int SomeOtherClass::*function() { return 0; } // This won't work
```

Again, the declarations differ semantically. Only the first function correctly defines a member function returning a pointer.